# How to fix kmeans error in r : 'more cluster centers than distinct data points'

Tags: r, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

When I run a kmeans algorithm I receive this error :

```
Error in kmeans(x, 2, 15) : 
  more cluster centers than distinct data points.
```

How can this error be fixed and what does it mean ? I think my data points are distinct ?

Here are my files and the r code I am using to generate kmeans :

```
rnames.csv : 
"a1","a2","a3"

cells.csv : 
0,1,2,1,4,3,5,3,4

cnames.csv : 
"google","so","test"

cells = c(read.csv("c:\\data-files\\kmeans\\cells.csv", header = TRUE))
rnames = c(read.csv("c:\\data-files\\kmeans\\rnames.csv", header = TRUE))
cnames = c(read.csv("c:\\data-files\\kmeans\\cnames.csv", header = TRUE))

x <- matrix(cells, nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(rnames, cnames))

# run K-Means
km <- kmeans(x, 2, 15)
```

Comment: It means exactly what it says: your data have fewer distinct cases than the number of centers you specified. That suggests that your data don't match the example you sketched out in the Q since when I read that data into a 3x3 matrix, `kmeans` runs just fine. When you actually get the error, check `x` carefully.

Comment: @joran yes, x was in indeed empty, my files just containt data (no headers) so when I changed to header=FALSE instead of header=TRUE it does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix for this is to use :

```
cells = c(read.csv("c:\\data-files\\kmeans\\cells.csv", header = FALSE))
rnames = c(read.csv("c:\\data-files\\kmeans\\rnames.csv", header = FALSE))
cnames = c(read.csv("c:\\data-files\\kmeans\\cnames.csv", header = FALSE))
```

instead of

```
cells = c(read.csv("c:\\data-files\\kmeans\\cells.csv", header = TRUE))
rnames = c(read.csv("c:\\data-files\\kmeans\\rnames.csv", header = TRUE))
cnames = c(read.csv("c:\\data-files\\kmeans\\cnames.csv", header = TRUE))
```